# Server Computer is not listed in My Network places

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2003, administrator

The server computer is not listed in my network places, when I opened the network from the client computer. We are using Windows 2003 Server and all other client computer installed Windows 7 64-bit. (I don't Want to change/install windows 2003 to windows server 2008 R2).

How can I get the Server to list in my Network places?

Comment: The easiest way is .. you see network setting in the other computer .. and make it same way ..

Comment: Can you access it from your computer? I mean, if you type in \\server\someSharedFolder does it respond? Can you ping the server? Is the issue only with your computer or all the office computers?

Comment: @DaveRook: yes .. I can access server from Client computer , I can access shared folder .  But Server  not listing in my network places , all other computer listed there except server.

Answer (score 1):

Need update 2003 Active directory schem to 2008 R2.

Get CD Windows 2008 R2 Server

```
<CD>:\support\adprep\
```

use `adprep.exe` or `adprep32.exe`

Schema Master:

```
ADPREP /forestprep
```

Infrastructure Master:

```
ADPREP /domainprep 
ADPREP /domainprep /gpprep
```

OS Version Schema Version

> Windows 2012 56
>   Windows 2008 R2 47
>   Windows 2008 44
>   Windows 2003 R2 31
>   Windows 2003 30
>   Windows 2000 13

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to your network group. Try changing the network location of your computer to either Home or Work!

[More details and reading](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/why-are-computers-missing-from-the-network-map)

More options include

> The computer is running Windows 7 or Windows Vista and the Link Layer Topology Discovery (LLTD) protocol is disabled on the network adapter. Windows uses the LLTD protocol to map computers and devices on a network. To enable LLTD, follow these steps:
>
> Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View network connections.
>
> Right-click the network connection, and then click Properties.
>
> Select the Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver and Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder check boxes, and then click OK.
>
> The computer is running Windows 7 or Windows Vista and network discovery is turned off. To turn on network discovery, follow these steps:
>
> Open Advanced sharing settings by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type network, click Network and Sharing Center, and then, in the left pane, click Change advanced sharing settings.
>
> Click the chevron Picture of the chevron icon to expand the Home or Work network profile.
>
> Click Turn on network discovery, and then click Save changes. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

**EDIT**

This is probably a permissions issue; add a folder to the server, share it with everyone (sharing and security if safe to do so) and then try. Since you've tried this and it worked, it means the problem is with the permissions you've got set up/configured.

Comment: Actually, From Any Client Computer (Windows 7) network places folder listing  All Other Computers  Which Running under the Domain Except The Server Computer . (The network set-up is One win 2003 server computer and 20 Clients(win 7) )computer.

Comment: @ DaveRook:Yes .. I did ..all your 3 suggestion for turning On the Network discovery. and checked the Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver and Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder

Comment: @RageeshGr Can the server see the computers?

Comment: @ DaveRook:Yes..From Server (**Entire Network --> Microsoft Windows Network--> <domain name>**) listing All computer except Sever Computer  Name

Comment: @RageeshGr Can you add a shared folder please to your server. Stick a file on the desktop and share it, giving it full permissions under sharing  and security

Comment: yes I can add a shared folder(as you said) , that can access from any client.

Comment: @RageeshGr So, the problem then is just a permissions issue. Can you go to a computer and type `\\servername\c$` and see if that works (replacing servername with the name of your server :) ?

Comment: when I click enter \\servername\C$ , first i get a credential windows then I gave the credential details but an error message popup says that **" \\servername\C$ is not accessible .You might not have permission to use this network resources ......"** like that  . but I gave the network admin Credentials..

Comment: Then it is a permissions issue - you don't have the permissions you think, or may not be in the group you thought or similar